# Use of token code when accessing OneDrive using Python

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am writing some code to move files over to OneDrive (enterprise account). My app is authenticated in Azure AD and should have the correct accesses (Files.ReadWrite.All in MS Graph, Sites.ReadWrite.All in Office365 SPO and User.Read in Azure AD).

The code to receive the app token works fine:

```
import msal

client_id = 'dc185bb*************6bcda94'
authority_host_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'
discovery_uri = 'https://api.office.com/discovery/'
client_secret = 'VsY7vV**************ToiA0='
tenant = '4a6*********************65079'
authority_uri = authority_host_uri + '/' + tenant
scopes=['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id, authority=authority_uri,
    client_credential=client_secret)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scopes)
print(result)
```

However, when I try to use this token with the OneDrive SDK library it seems like I am not able pass it through:

```
def __init__(self, http_provider, client_id=None, scopes=None, access_token=None, session_type=None, loop=None,
             auth_server_url=None, auth_token_url=None):
    """Initialize the authentication provider for authenticating
    requests sent to OneDrive

    Args:
        http_provider (:class:`HttpProviderBase<onedrivesdk.http_provider_base>`):
            The HTTP provider to use for all auth requests
        client_id (str): Defaults to None, the client id for your
            application
        scopes (list of str): Defaults to None, the scopes 
            that are required for your application
        access_token (str): Defaults to None. Not used in this implementation.
```

The above is from the auth_provider.py part of the onedrivesdk, and clearly states the access_token is not used in the implementation.

Is there another way around this? Or other libraries to use?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this Authentication of [OneDrive for Business](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python#onedrive-for-business).

```
import onedrivesdk
from onedrivesdk.helpers import GetAuthCodeServer
from onedrivesdk.helpers.resource_discovery import ResourceDiscoveryRequest

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080'
client_id = your_client_id
client_secret = your_client_secret
discovery_uri = 'https://api.office.com/discovery/'
auth_server_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize'
auth_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token'

http = onedrivesdk.HttpProvider()
auth = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(http,
                                client_id,
                                auth_server_url=auth_server_url,
                                auth_token_url=auth_token_url)
auth_url = auth.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
auth.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret, resource=discovery_uri)
# If you have access to more than one service, you'll need to decide
# which ServiceInfo to use instead of just using the first one, as below.
service_info = ResourceDiscoveryRequest().get_service_info(auth.access_token)[0]
auth.redeem_refresh_token(service_info.service_resource_id)
client = onedrivesdk.OneDriveClient(service_info.service_resource_id + '/_api/v2.0/', auth, http)
```

Upload an Item:

```
returned_item = client.item(drive='me', id='root').children['newfile.txt'].upload('./path_to_file.txt')
```

For more examples, you can refer to this [link](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python#examples).